# Errors running sklearn in AWS EC2

Tags: python, amazon-ec2, scikit-learn

I just started using AWS EC2 today and ran into some errors with sklearn. I installed the sklearn module using the following line:

```
curl https://gist.githubusercontent.com/dacamo76/4780765/raw/c3779996d8f6b13caaaa48d33aa1585684c7f8e6/scikit-learn-install.sh | sh
```

Which was sourced from this question:

https://gist.github.com/dacamo76/4780765

However, after attempting to run a python script, I received the error:

```
ImportError: No module named sklearn.
```

I deduced it had something to do with dependencies, so I attempted to implement the solution offered [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/599468/importerror-no-module-named-sklearn).

I attempted to build the dependencies first using this line:

```
sudo yum install build-essential python-dev python-setuptools python-numpy python-scipy libatlas-dev libatlas3gf-base
```

But that only yielded output like: 'No package build-essential available.' If anyone could help me resolve the issue, it would be tremendously appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Which OS are you using on your AWS?

Comment: I am using the Amazon Linux AMI 2016.09.1 image for EC2. My own laptop is running on a 64-bit Windows 10 Home OS.

Comment: Have a look at: http://serverfault.com/questions/204893/aws-ec2-and-build-essential